# Intersection of a downward directed family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $Y\subseteq X$ a nonempty subset. Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $X$ and let $K=\{K_i: i\in I\}$ be a directed family of subsets of $X$ containing $Y$. That is, for any $i,j\in I$ there exist $l\in I$ such that $K_l\subseteq K_i\cap K_j$.

I may add a comment to clarify my notation: For a subset $H\subseteq X$, $H/R=\{ [x]_R: x\in H\}$, that is, the set of $R$-classes of elements in $H$. It is also important that I am not assuming that any of the $K_i$ is the union of $R$-classes, that is, it may happen that $[x]_R=[y]_R$ and $x\in K_i$ but $y\notin K_i$. This is the real problem because otherwise the answer to the question would be trivial.

> My question is the following: Does
> $(\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}K_i)/R=\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}(K_i/R)$? (and does the cardinality of $I$ matter?)

For me it is clear that $(\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}K_i)/R\subseteq\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}(K_i/R)$. However, I am not able to prove the other inclusion. I can find examples where the equality does not hold if the family $K$ is not directed even for finite $I$

Edit 2: I posted this question thinking that it might be a set-theoretic property, in the context I was working $R$ is a $\emptyset$-type-definable equivalence relation and all $K_i$ are $\emptyset$-type-definable sets. In that case, one can use compactness theorem to prove the equality.

Comment: when you can't prove something, you might try constructing a counterexample.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I tried but I was not able to construct a counterexample if the family is directed

Comment: What do you mean by $(\bigcap_{i\in I}K_i)/R$ ? Is it $\left\{A\in X/R\,:\, \exists u\in\bigcap_{i\in I} K_i,\ u\in A\right\}$ ?

Comment: just a suggestion.  i dunno whether this work or not: maybe you can try something like $X = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ infinite dimensional vector space, $K_i$ be some cylinder with finitely many zeros.

Comment: @Gae.S. Yes, exactly that

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I will keep thinking about it and post if I get something relevant

Comment: Define A/R.....

Comment: You've said nothing about $R$, not even that it's an equivalence relation, though your notation suggests that must be what you have in mind. You've placed no conditions on its connection with the $K_i$, and unless you do then the righthand side of what you say you're trying to prove isn't even defined. If some $K_I$ is not closed under $R$ — that is, if there are $x, y \in X$ with $x\in K_i$ and $x R y$ but $y\notin K_i$ — then what does $K_i / R$  mean??

Comment: @BrianO Sorry you are right, I will add more information to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb{N}$, $R$ the equivalence relation with two classes: $\{0\}$ and $\{n\mid n>0\}$, $Y=\{0\}$, and $K_i = \{0\}\cup \{ n\in \mathbb{N}\mid n> i\}$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then $\left(\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}} K_i\right)/R=\{0\}/R=\{\{0\}\}$ but $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}} (K_i/R)$ contains both $R$-classes, since both are represented in each $K_i$.